# How to extract AOSP build configurationfor a specific device

Tags: android, linux-kernel, cyanogenmod

I want to see what is actually compiled from all the source that I've downloaded when I run `brunch i9100`. In particular I want to lokkat the correct drivers and HAL sources.

How can I know that. I mean I can configure my own kernel build by make menuconfig, but I want to know what is configured for the i9100 device (galaxy s2).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find something from samsung open source

http://opensource.samsung.com/reception/receptionSub.do?method=sub&sub=F&searchValue=i9100